# Definition of limit with$ f(x)=|x^3|$

Tags: limits, derivatives, absolute-value

Using the definition of the limit I tried to find the derivative of $f(x)=|x^3|$. I came up with: $$f'(x)=\frac{3x^5}{|x^3|}$$

**Question:** Why is the derivative (according to this answer) not defined for $x=0$ (division by zero) while $f'(0)$ actually exists, since: $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{|x^3|-|0^3|}{x-0}=0$$

**Elaboration using the definition of the limit:**

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|(x+h)^3|-|x^3|}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{(x+h)^6}-\sqrt{x^6}}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^6-x^6}{h(\sqrt{(x+h)^6}+\sqrt{x^6})}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^5 + 6 h^4 x + 15 h^3 x^2 + 20 h^2 x^3 + 15 h x^4 + 6 x^5}{(\sqrt{(x+h)^6}+\sqrt{x^6})}$$
$$=\frac{6x^5}{2\sqrt{x^6}}=\frac{3x^5}{|x^3|}$$
Which is not defined for $x=0$.

Comment: How did you get from $$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^5 + 6 h^4 x + 15 h^3 x^2 + 20 h^2 x^3 + 15 h x^4 + 6 x^5}{(\sqrt{(x+h)^6}+\sqrt{x^6})}$$ to $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{6x^5}{2\sqrt{x^6}}?$$ It looks to me like a step or two is missing...

Comment: By applying $h -> 0$

Comment: The case of the derivative at $x = 0$ is interesting. Consider that case, and the cases $x > 0$ and $x < 0$ separately. It will make the calculations much more straightforward.

Comment: When You say the limit you found is not defined, you are  wrong.

Comment: @ImreVégh But if you apply $h\to 0$, then the limit must dissapear.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon: but it isn't defined at 0 is it? Because of the division by zero?

Comment: @SimonS: but it should be possible by using the definition of the limit... or should it not?

Comment: Oh I see my mistake . since you still wrote the lim part I thought you meant when x tends to zero.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon: if $f(x)=\frac{x}{x}$ then the limit for x to 0 goes to 1, but f(0) itself doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Let's tackle first the problem for $x=0$. Observe that $|a^3|=a^2\,|a|$, so
$$
f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|(0+h)^3|-0}{h}=
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|h^3|}{h}=
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h^2\,|h|}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}h\,|h|=0
$$

For $x\ne0$:
\begin{align}
f'(x)
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{(x+h)^6}-\sqrt{x^6}}{h}\\[6px]
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^6-x^6}{h(\sqrt{(x+h)^6}+\sqrt{x^6})}\\[6px]
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h(6x^5+hp(x,h))}{h(\sqrt{(x+h)^6}+\sqrt{x^6})}\\[6px]
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{6x^5+hp(x,h)}{\sqrt{(x+h)^6}+\sqrt{x^6}}\\[6px]
&=\frac{6x^5}{2|x|^3}=\frac{3x^5}{x^2|x|}=\frac{3x^3}{|x|}
\end{align}
(where $p(x,h)$ is some polynomial in $x$ and $h$ that you can compute explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the limit from below ($x$ tending from negative to zero) and from above separately. They both evaluate to zero.

Comment: I understand, but why is this not reflected when I use the definition of the limit, which leads to a division by zero?

Comment: Not if it's a limit evaluation. Consider e.g. L'Hopital's rule for limits of quotients.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was saying that

$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^5 + 6 h^4 x + 15 h^3 x^2 + 20 h^2 x^3 + 15 h x^4 + 6 x^5}{(\sqrt{(x+h)^6}+\sqrt{x^6})}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{6x^5}{2\sqrt{x^6}}$$

which is not true. If you set $h$ to $0$, then you must set **all** values of $h$ to $0$, and drop the limit all together. You cannot just set some of them to $0$. For exapmle, you cannot say

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac hh = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac0h = 0$$
because the first equality is not true.

What you get in your limit calculation is

$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^5 + 6 h^4 x + 15 h^3 x^2 + 20 h^2 x^3 + 15 h x^4 + 6 x^5}{(\sqrt{(x+h)^6}+\sqrt{x^6})}=\\=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{6x^5}{\sqrt{(x+h)^6}+\sqrt{x^6}}+\frac{h(h^4 + 6 h^3 x + 15 h^2 x^2 + 20 h^1 x^3 + 15  x^4)}{\sqrt{(x+h)^6}+\sqrt{x^6}}$$

Which is equal to the sum of limits of both sumands, if both limits exist.

Now, you can easily see that

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{6x^5}{\sqrt{(x+h)^6}+\sqrt{x^6}} = 3\mathrm{sign}(x)x^2$$ **no matter what the value of $x$ is**. If $x=0$, the limit becomes $$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{0}{\sqrt{h^6}}$$ and is equal to $0=3\cdot 0^2.$

For the second limit, you can also quickly see that it is $0$ no matter what the value of $x$ is. If $x\neq 0$, then the result is obvious, if $x=0$, then the limit is $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h^5}{\sqrt{h^6}}=\lim_{h\to 0} h^2\cdot\mathrm{sign}(h)=0$$

Comment: Sorry, but your “no matter what the value of $x$ is” is simply wrong. The derivative must be negative for $x<0$, because the function is *obviously* decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$. Similarly, I'd grade the last computation as “failure”. The limit is $0$, but not for the reason you're giving. Are you sure that $\sqrt{a^2}=a$, which is what you seem to believe?

Comment: @egreg Yeah, at some point I forgot we are calculating the derivative of $|x^3|$, not $x^3$. I fixed my mistakes now. I was focused on the mistake the OP made, thanks for the corrections. The last computation is sloppy, but the result is correct. I also fixed it.